# OpenSSL public key and private key generation failed in GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

I just wrote a simple PHP function that generate public key and private key pair.

Locally, it works great. But in Google App Engine, it doesn't produce any key pair. I check that all necessary PHP functions are exists in GAE. But why this is not generating the key pair. Locally I was using PHP7.1 and in GAE PHP version 5.5.38. Also `openssl` is enabled in GAE. Any hints? Should I use any other similar methods to generate key pair while my app will be in GAE?

```php
<?php

var_dump(function_exists("openssl_pkey_new"));
var_dump(function_exists("openssl_pkey_export"));
var_dump(function_exists("openssl_pkey_get_details"));


function generateKeyPair($config = [])
{
    $defaultConfig = array(
        "digest_alg" => "sha512",
        "private_key_bits" => 4096,
        "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    );
    $config = array_merge($defaultConfig, $config);
    $res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
    openssl_pkey_export($res, $privateKey);
    $publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
    $publicKey = $publicKey["key"];
    return $key = [
        'private_key' => $privateKey,
        'public_key' => $publicKey
    ];
}

/**
 * Locally it works well. But in Google App Engine
 * 
 * Output: bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) array ('private_key' => NULL, 'public_key' => NULL)
 */
var_export(generateKeyPair());
```

Comment: Ok. I didn't get any answer yet. But I was in hurry and I solved this by using phpseclib. It easily product the key pair. Still I will be waiting for new thoughts with solutions. But for now, I just get it to work.